# Oracle SYSAUX free blocks

Tags: oracle

My Oracle SYSAUS Space usage, how do I clean it up? Please Help

```
Server Manageability - Advisor Framework      29,093.44 SYS
Server Manageability - Optimizer Statistics History    1,738.50 SYS
AUDSYS schema objects      1,111.88 AUDSYS
Unified Job Scheduler        135.88 SYS
Server Manageability - Other Components       62.38 SYS
XDB       62.25 XDB
Server Manageability - Automatic Workload Repository          27.75 SYS
```

Comment: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2305512.1  **SYSAUX Tablespace Grows Rapidly After Upgrading Database to 12.2.0.1 Due To Statistics Advisor (Doc ID 2305512.1)**

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 12.2.0, does it help. I need the SQL cmds to clean up or som kind of procedure. btw: i don't have a Oracle Login yet